# Version control questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about version control software, like Git or Subversion, on-topic on SQA?

Answer (score 5):

I would say that they are, especially as pertains to automated testing and versioning the automation code.

Say you wrote some automated tests for feature X in Version Y of your application.  In Version Y+1 of the application, they add a bell to feature X that needs tested.  Obviously, you're going to want to update your automation for feature X.  You could just do it and be done.  But what if there is a patch release of Version Y, say version Ya, that you need to run your automation for feature X?  You would want to be able to roll back or retrieve your automation code from Version Y to be able to execute against that test so you aren't polluted with the new code from version Y+1.

Or, even simpler than that.  What if you're working on coding automation for the new bell and just want to scrap it all and start over because it's just not working out.  Using version control, it's a simple roll back.

Both these reasons I've had to do in the past and it would be a serious PITA if I didn't have the version control tool in place.

Comment: we version control manual tests also

Answer (score 4):

I'd say questions like this one are definitely on topic:

[How to version a RFT project](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/439/how-to-version-a-rft-project/486#486)

There is going to be a big overlap between software tools commonly used by programmers, and those commonly used by testers. I'm not sure there will be a hard & fast rule we can apply there.

Comment: I also believe that is on topic. The reason is that it's USING svn to supplement an sqa tool, not just general usage of the tool.

Answer (score 3):

I would say they're not, at least not directly.

If they directly to pertain to your role in SQA, for example getting the latest build into the QA environment, then I would say they have a claim. For just standard questions about their use, I would say no - that seems more StackOverflow related.

From the SO FAQ

if your question generally covers …

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- **software tools commonly used by programmers <---- ***
- matters that are unique to the programming profession